# (SQL) Match users belong to which group given user_id[]

Tags: sql

user table

```
ID | name 
1  | ada    
2  | bob   
3  | tom
```

group Table

```
ID | name
1  | group A
2  | group B
3  | group C
```

user_group Table

```
user_id | group_id
1       | 1
2       | 1
1       | 2
2       | 2
3       | 2
1       | 3
3       | 3
```

Given group of user ids : [1, 2, 3]

How to query the group that all users in the above list belongs to? (in this case: Group B)

Comment: If you can guarantee `user_id, group_id` is unique - then `COUNT` + `GROUP BY` + `HAVING`

Comment: how is user_id 2 belongs to group C. i think group b is what you required?

Comment: yes, group B, thanks Dinup

Comment: nice question, i think can be done using collect, but thats not standard

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get all groups that contain exactly the specified users (i.e. all specified users and no other users)

```
DECLARE @numUsers int = 3

SELECT ug.group_id
       --The Max doesn't really do anything here because all
       --groups with the same group id have the same name.  The
       --max is just used so we can select the group name eventhough
       --we aren't aggregating across group names
     , MAX(g.name) AS name
FROM user_group ug
--Filter to only groups with three users
JOIN (SELECT group_id FROM user_group GROUP BY group_id HAVING COUNT(*) = @numUsers) ug2
  ON ug.group_id = ug2.group_id
JOIN [group] g
    ON ug.group_id = g.ID
WHERE user_id IN (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY ug.group_id
--The distinct is only necessary if user_group
--isn't keyed by group_id, user_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) = @numUsers
```

To get groups that contain all specified users:

```
    DECLARE @numUsers int = 3    

    SELECT ug.group_id
           --The Max doesn't really do anything here because all
           --groups with the same group id have the same name.  The
           --max is just used so we can select the group name eventhough
           --we aren't aggregating across group names
         , MAX(g.name) AS name
    FROM user_group ug
    JOIN [group] g
        ON ug.group_id = g.ID
    WHERE user_id IN (1, 2, 3)
    GROUP BY ug.group_id
    --The distinct is only necessary if user_group
    --isn't keyed by group_id, user_id
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) = 3
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0e968/3

Comment: i think you dont need that join

Comment: @FUD The `JOIN` just to get information from the group table which is the information the OP seems to want.

Comment: yea i take that back, your solution only breaks for duplicate rows but thats about data sanity. +1

Comment: @FUD I've edited my answer to provide the correct group even if user_group isn't keyed on `group_id, user_id`.

Comment: But that would fail if user 1,2,3,4 are in group D, and we just want to find out 1,2,3 to be in group C

Comment: @DavidNg I didn't understand exactly what you were looking for.  I've updated my answer to return either groups that contain all the specified users and no other users or groups that contain contain all the specified users.  The first query is more specific and will always return a subset of the second query.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
Select t2.name         
     FROM        
    (Select group_id 
       From 
        user_group 
      Group by group_id 
     Having Count(user_id) = (Select Count(*) FROM User_Table)) AS T1        
     INNER JOIN        
       Group_Table AS T2
         ON T1.group_id = T2.ID
```

See Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fa7250/4

Comment: This is not a general solution if we want to know the group that users[1,3] both in ...

Comment: I thought you want to check for all the mebers available in user table.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select UserID,count(*)
From UserGroupTable
group by UserID
```

This will give a count of 3 where the UserID/GroupID is unique (as zerkms pointed out)

Comment: this is not a goodsolution what if i want only [1,2] your solution will return group 1 and 3 , which is wrong

Comment: The question asks "given user_id[]"..  so a WHERE clause/ or similar way of restricting the query is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name FROM group_tbl WHERE id IN (SELECT g_id FROM user_grp GROUP BY g_id HAVING Count(u_id)=(SELECT Count(id) FROM user_tbl));
```